# C++ - Can't overwrite file with a single byte in binary mode after reading it (Windows 10)

Tags: c++11, binaryfiles

**EDIT:**
I have a problem with this little piece of code. I'm new to C++ and I need to understand how to write a byte (or a multiple bytes) inside a file in binary mode.

With this code I'm reading the first 11 bytes of foo.txt. Inside foo.txt there is this string "Hello World!!!". On the console we see "Hello World". Until here it's all ok!

The problem is that I can't overwrite the entire file (or few bytes) after reading into, why? On Ubuntu it overwrites the byte in position 11, not on Windows. On Windows it doesn't do nothing!

The file is opened in read/write mode with parameters ios_base::in | ios_base::out. When I use file.write() it should overwrites the data with byte 3F (in ASCII the string "?"). It doesn't happen, why?

**PLEASE TRY TO RUN THIS CODE! (change workingDirectory)**

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string workingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\francesco\\Documents\\Test\\";
    string inputFile = workingDirectory + "foo.txt";
    fstream file;
    file.open(inputFile, ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
    char *buffer = new char [11];
    file.read(buffer, 11);

    cout << "Track:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        cout << buffer[i];
    };

    cout << endl;
    delete[] buffer;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "The file is still open!" <<  endl;
        int num = 63; // 0x3F ASCII --> ?
        file.write((char*)&num, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "We shoudln't reach this part of code!" << endl;
    }

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

At the moment I resolved the problem closing and reopening file (or seek again to byte 11). It is interesting to know why on Windows we have to do this after reading operation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, the library has a different (incorrect) behaviour with different OSes.

**EDIT:**

From C11 standard, ISO/IEC 9899:2011:

> ...input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

Read [here](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus06.html#FSTREAM) also for C++ library:

> Once a file has been opened in read and write mode, the << operator can be used to insert information into the file, while the >> operator may be used to extract information from the file. These operations may be performed in any order, but a seekg or seekp operation is required when switching between insertions and extractions. The seek operation is used to activate the stream's data used for reading or those used for writing (and vice versa). The istream and ostream parts of fstream objects share the stream's data buffer and by performing the seek operation the stream either activates its istream or its ostream part. If the seek is omitted, reading after writing and writing after reading simply fails.

These are the cases:

1. On Windows it overwrites first byte only if we don't previously read
   the first 11 bytes and opened the file in read/write mode
2. On Windows it CAN'T overwrites byte in position 11 (no errors) if we
   previously read the first 11 bytes and opened the file in read/write
   mode
3. On Windows after reading the first 11 bytes we have to seek to position 11 in order to overwrite byte in
   position 11
4. **On Ubuntu it overwrites byte in position 11 also if we previously
   read the first 11 bytes and opened the file in read/write mode**
5. On both OS if we open the file with ios_base::out only parameter it
   overwrites the entire file, not if we use ios_base::in also

At the moment **I resolved the problem closing and reopening file (and/or seek again to byte 11)**.

It is interesting to know why on Windows only we have to do this after reading operation.

Comment: That should essentially go into your question

Comment: You don't answer to the question: why on Windows we can't write after reading? Your suggestion to use flush() doesn't work

Comment: But your answer is not an answer to your own question

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20655676)

Comment: @mskfisher:
My answer reports how to write in the file after you have read it on Windows. You have to seek again into file. So it is the solution. Why Linux and Windows have different behaviour is another problem

Comment: @Francesco Unless I'm missing something, this answer looks like it contains the same information you stated in your question.  Your question above seems to be "why do we have to close/open on Windows", which this does not answer.

Comment: @mskfisher: I edited the question and the title hours ago. Please take a look, if it is not clear I'll change again

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to clear the error flag after your reading operations.

```
file.clear();
```

Comment: If I add file.clear(); after file.close() nothing changes. I don't understand why output file changes only the first time (without append it should be erased)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the input for your program, but my best guess is to add this:

```
if (file.rdstate() & std::ifstream::eofbit) {
    file.seekg(-1, file.end);
}
```

before `file.clear()`, maybe you hit end of file. Or if not just check if all error flags are ok after reading a file:

```
  if ( (is.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit ) != 0 )
    std::cerr << "Error opening 'test.txt'\n";
```

Comment: It is 65MB file, I read just 2048 bytes.

I can't believe that anyone here could explain this simple problem.

I open a file in read/write mode, read first 2048 bytes, print them on console then write a byte in the same file that should overwrite existent content

Comment: If I open the file in read mode only, then close the file open it again in write mode it works. It overwrite the file contents with a single byte. I'll try to check the error flags

Comment: I added your piece of code for checking flags, no error

Comment: Sorry for the same question but as message is misleading, you added code checking flags before clear call right?